# Unhandled Runtime Error. TypeError: Failed to fetch. Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

I have an adult-content website, and I have an error when I take one filter (name of my partner website):

[image]

When I refresh the page, the error disappears, and also if I go through the link in the new tab - it works fine, but if I want to take this filter from my website it crashes...
I don't have this problem inside the incognito browser window.
If I clear cache and cookies, I also don't have this problem for a while, but then it comes back.

I make my fetch inside getStaticProps inside `try catch` and catch does not detect the error.

Here is my next.config.js

```js
    const securityHeaders = [
      {
        key: 'Strict-Transport-Security',
        value: 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload',
      },
      {
        key: 'X-Frame-Options',
        value: 'SAMEORIGIN',
      },
      {
        key: 'Permissions-Policy',
        value: 'camera=(), microphone=(), geolocation=(), geolocation=()',
      },
      {
        key: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
        value: 'nosniff',
      },
      {
        key: 'Referrer-Policy',
        value: 'origin-when-cross-origin',
      },
    ];

    const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: false,
      swcMinify: true,
      redirects: async () => [
        {
          source: '/:path*',
          has: [{ type: 'host', value: 'www.example.com' }],
          destination: 'https://example.com/:path*',
          permanent: true,
        },
      ],
      images: {
        dangerouslyAllowSVG: true,
        contentSecurityPolicy: 'default-src "self"; script-src "none"; sandbox;',
        minimumCacheTTL: 300,
        domains: [
          'galleryn0.awemdia.com',
        ],
      },
      async headers() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/:path*',
            headers: securityHeaders,
          },
          {
            source: '/_next/:path*',
            headers: [
              {
                key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
                value: '*',
              },
            ],
          },
        ];
     },
    };

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I have tried to find something similar, but I could not get it

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed if by changing filter naming (name of my partner website) inside URL.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).